# Does the PCI Standard apply to storing information about paper checks

Tags: payment-gateway, pci-dss, pci-compliance

Does the PCI DSS standard apply to providers that solely work with check by phone ?

i.e collecting

1) Account numbers
2) Routing numbers
3) Check number

in other words - no credit cards

Thanks

Comment: Did you bother looking at the official docs? https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/

Comment: Yes, even went through the self assessment questionnaire. Cant find a reference to paper check . Fundamental question is does PCI DSS have any bearing on how paper checks are stored, processed (via check by phone) or is it the purview of Check 21 Act

Answer (score 1):

The title of the standard is the best clue: *Payment Card* Industry - Data Security Standard.
It applies to the storage of payment card details.

Check page 7 of the PCI DSS standard here: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_v2.pdf

Checks do not normally have a payment card primary account number printed on them so PCI-DSS would not normally apply.